# How to get the original resource identifier of a button?

Tags: android, button

In my layout xml file I have several buttons like this which share the same event handler:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/page1" onClick="OnClick" .... ></Button>
```

In my activity I would like something like this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  String url = String.format("http://example.com/%d", v.getId());
}
```

to dynamically build the url. However, getId() returns the integer representing the button ID, not the word "page1".

Of course I could use a switch statement, but it would be much more convenient if I could refer to the original ID name assigned to the button.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getResources().getResourceName()`

Comment: Nice! Actually, getResourceName() returns the full identifier; getResourceEntryName() gives just the button name. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Reflection or, set the android:tag attribute, and then use .getTag(), simpler from code, but a bit redundancy in the.xml.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning reflections. I am new to Java and didn't know this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflections on generated R.id class.
Or, better you can create own class with field containing value you want to know.